# Sending DTMF tones from dialpad

Tags: java, android

I have the following code which works perfectly fine. I am using the dial pad to set the number and also to send the DTMF tones. But I find the code to bit more repitive. Is there any better way to optimize the code or the approach I have is good enough ?
Thank you in advance for your valuable suggestions. Cheers :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btnZero, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btnAsh, btnHash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Buttons
    btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
    btn3 = findViewById(R.id.btnThree);
    btn4 = findViewById(R.id.btnFour);
    btn5 = findViewById(R.id.btnFive);
    btn6 = findViewById(R.id.btnSix);
    btn7 = findViewById(R.id.btnSeven);
    btn8 = findViewById(R.id.btnEight);
    btn9 = findViewById(R.id.btnNine);
    btnZero = findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
    btnAsh = findViewById(R.id.btnAsterisk);
    btnHash = findViewById(R.id.btnHash);

    dialPadTone();
}

public dialPadTone() {
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn9.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnZero.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAsh.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnHash.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // Read current phone dialPadnumber
    String phoneNo = dialPadnumber.getText().toString();
    int value;
    if (btnZero.equals(view)) {
        value = 48;
        phoneNo += btnZero.getText();
    } else if (btn1.equals(view)) {
        value = 49;
        phoneNo += btn1.getText();
    } else if (btn2.equals(view)) {
        value = 50;
        phoneNo += btn2.getText();
    } else if (btn3.equals(view)) {
        value = 51;
        phoneNo += btn3.getText();
    } else if (btn4.equals(view)) {
        value = 52;
        phoneNo += btn4.getText();
    } else if (btn5.equals(view)) {
        value = 53;
        phoneNo += btn5.getText();
    } else if (btn6.equals(view)) {
        value = 54;
        phoneNo += btn6.getText();
    } else if (btn7.equals(view)) {
        value = 55;
        phoneNo += btn7.getText();
    } else if (btn8.equals(view)) {
        value = 56;
        phoneNo += btn8.getText();
    } else if (btn9.equals(view)) {
        value = 57;
        phoneNo += btn9.getText();
    } else if (btnAsh.equals(view)) {
        value = 42;
    } else if (btnHash.equals(view)) {
        value = 35;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + view.getId());
    }

    setPhoneNum(phoneNo);
    Intent intent = new Intent("send_dtmf_tones");
    Message message = new DTMFtones(
            value
    );
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [android:onClick](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-click-events-button-android/) attribute to get rid of the boilerplate calls to `setOnClickListener` and `findViewById`.

The giant if-else statement is very repetitive. The actions taken in all branches are assigning a value to the `value` variable and appending a digit to the phone number. You could convert the code to data by mapping the button label to a value and a string.

```
final String label = ((Button) view).getText();
final int value = buttonLabelToValue.get(label);
phoneNo += buttonLabelToPhoneNumberDigit.get(label);
```

Handle the two special cases '#' and '*' by mapping the PhoneNumberDigit to an empty string.

I never write code to prepare for an UI component calling a wrong listener method. I define the UI and the listeners and if my UI calls the wrong method then it's a bug. My tests must be good enough to catch such scenarios. In this example, not checking the return value of `buttonLabelToValue.get(...)` for nulls results in `NullPointerException` instead of the `IllegalStateException` thrown in your version. Not much difference for the user as the app crashes in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will rework it :)